# Get list of index of elements of a series in another series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, series

Sorry for the confusing title, but i dont know how to explain this without an example.

I need to get a list of positions of items from one series in another series. The example i was give is the following:

```
ser1 = pandas.Series([10, 9, 6, 5, 3, 1, 12, 8, 13])
ser2 = pandas.Series([1, 3, 10, 13])
```

The solution should be `[5, 4, 0, 8]`

I first thought of using `numpy.where(ser1.isin(ser2))` but the array of idex i get is in the wrong order: `[0, 4, 5, 8]`

If I use `ser2.isin(ser1)`, i get an array of boolean values. Is there a way to get the index of elements instead of this? Or any other way to solve this using other methods?

Comment: What would be the expected output for `ser1=pd.Series([10, 9, 6, 1, 3, 1, 12, 8]`?

Comment: Are the values always small (bounded) integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use broadcasting in numpy for compare with `argmax` for correct ordering:

```
out = (ser2.to_numpy() == ser1.to_numpy()[:, None]).argmax(axis=0)
[5, 4, 0, 8]
```

Solution if some value not matched with `np.where` and `any`:

```
ser1=pd.Series([10, 9, 6, 1, 3, 1, 12, 8, 13])
ser2 = pd.Series([1, 3, 10, 130])

m = ser2.to_numpy() == ser1.to_numpy()[:, None]
out = np.where(m.any(axis=0), m.argmax(axis=0), np.nan)
print (out)
[ 3.  4.  0. nan]
```

Comment: Note that the algorithm complexity of the solution is quadratic, which is not great for big arrays.